# Eigen sparse solver wrong results

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra, eigen

I am trying to solve a sparse linear system **Ax=B** with the Eigen library in C++, however the following trivial example seems to give an incorrect solution:

```
#include <Eigen/SparseCholesky>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main(){

    SimplicialLDLT<SparseMatrix<double>> solver;
    SparseMatrix<double> A(9,9);
    typedef Triplet<double> T;
    vector<T> triplet;
    VectorXd B(9);

    for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
        triplet.push_back(T(i,i,1));
        triplet.push_back(T(i+5,i+5,1));
    }

    triplet.push_back(T(4,1,-1));
    triplet.push_back(T(4,3,-1));
    triplet.push_back(T(4,5,-1));
    triplet.push_back(T(4,7,-1));
    triplet.push_back(T(4,4,4));

    A.setFromTriplets(triplet.begin(),triplet.end());
    B << 0,0,0,0,0.387049,0,0,0,0;

    solver.compute(A);
    VectorXd x = solver.solve(B);

    cout << "A\n" << A << "\n";
    cout << "B\n" << B << "\n";
    cout << "x\n" << x << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I don't see any errors, the algorithm returns "0" meaning "Success", however the solution I get is

```
x = 0 0.193524 0 0.193524 0.193524 0 0 0 0
```

which is obviously not the solution to this system, the correct one is

```
x = 0 0 0 0 0.0967621 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: I’m not expert in linear algebra, but you can try 2 things. 1. Compute determinant of the matrix, ensure it’s not zero. If zero, it means your linear system doesn’t have exactly one solution, either none at all or infinite number of them. 2. Try different solvers, Eigen has quite a few of them. Replace your `SimplicialLDLT` with `SparseLU` or `ConjugateGradient` and see what happens.

Comment: Fortunately the matrix is not singular, now I just tried the **sparseLU** solver as you suggested, and it worked. That's great, however I don't really understand why...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here's documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SimplicialLDLT.html) for `SimplicialLDLT` solver:

> This class provides a LDL^T Cholesky factorizations without square root of sparse matrices **that are selfadjoint and positive definite**.

When the matrix stores real numbers in the elements, self-adjoint == symmetrical. Your matrix is clearly not symmetrical. Also, not every symmetrical matrix is positive-definite, [see examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_symmetric_matrix#Examples).

In short, the solver you have chosen is only applicable to very narrow class of matrices. As you have already discovered, `SparseLU` solver works for your input data.

`ConjugateGradient` solver will not work either, it doesn’t require the matrix to be positive-definite but [it does](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ConjugateGradient.html) require it to be self-adjoint.

Comment: CG requires a selfadjoint positive (semi-) definite `A` -- there are some variants which don't require that, but (implicitly) solve `(A^T*A) * x = A^T * b`.