# Eigen sparse solvers give drastically different solutions for the same linear system

Tags: c++, math, geometry, linear-algebra, eigen

I am trying to solve a sparse linear system as quickly as possible using eigen.

The docs give you 4 sparse solvers toc hoose from (but really it;s more like these three):

```
SimplicialLLT
#include<Eigen/SparseCholesky>  Direct LLt factorization    SPD Fill-in reducing    LGPL    

SimplicialLDLT is often preferable

SimplicialLDLT
#include<Eigen/SparseCholesky>  Direct LDLt factorization   SPD Fill-in reducing    LGPL    

Recommended for very sparse and not too large problems (e.g., 2D Poisson eq.)

SparseLU
#include<Eigen/SparseLU>    LU factorization    Square  Fill-in reducing, Leverage fast dense algebra   MPL2    

optimized for small and large problems with irregular patterns
```

When I use the last solver, i.e. I do:

```
Eigen::SparseLU<Eigen::SparseMatrix<Scalar>> solver(bijection);
Assert(solver.info() == Eigen::Success, "Matrix is degenerate.");
solver.compute(bijection);
Assert(solver.info() == Eigen::Success, "Matrix is degenerate.");

Eigen::VectorXf vertices_u = solver.solve(u);
Assert(solver.info() == Eigen::Success, "Matrix is degenerate.");
Eigen::VectorXf vertices_v = solver.solve(v);
Assert(solver.info() == Eigen::Success, "Matrix is degenerate.");
```

I get the correct result, which graphically looks like this:

[image]

If I use simplicialLDLT, i.e. if I change the solver line and nothing else to:

```
Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<Scalar>> solver(bijection);
```

I get this degenerate monstrosity:

[image]

Basically the two solvers are returining wildely different results for the exact same sparse system. How is this possible?

None of the error checks return false, so in both versions the matrices are considered to be fine.

Comment: Not 100% sure if it's a dupe but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583888/eigen-sparse-solver-wrong-results

Comment: It should be symmetric and positive definite however. Maybe I can check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicSparseSystems.html => SimplicialLDLT only for SPD matrices. You might try a least squares approach https://snaildove.github.io/2017/08/01/positive_definite_and_least_square/